# JQuery filter results controls?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an mvc3 webgrid that contains results that I would like to filter by for each column.  I'm looking for something similar to the screenshot below regarding filtering (dropdowns with multiple checkboxes for each column entry)?  Can somebody provide code or available jquery controls to achieve this UI functionality?

[image]

DISCLAIMER for editors: This is a general ask.  Not sure what "technical" criteria needs to be called out here but if you need more info please inquire about what I can include to make this helpful or less ambigous and I can edit my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply query your result set for distinct values on the column you want to do this for, then add a row to your grid which contains drop down lists of those values. And then combine that with [jQuery Column Filters](http://tomcoote.co.uk/wp-content/CodeBank/Demos/columnFilters/demo.html) as **nathan gonzalez**.

or use something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Grid_Paging_In_MVC3.aspx)

Or you could use [Telerik's MVC Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) which has this out of the box, and is free (Open Source licence)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Column Filters](http://tomcoote.co.uk/code-bank/jquery-column-filters/) isn't exactly what you have there with the checkboxes, but it will filter by text input for each column.